# Skrollr breaks after page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, css, page-refresh, skrollr

[My website](http://www.galanagettingmarried.com/the-couple) uses Skrollr to create a parallax effect on the background of the main page.. It works perfectly... unless you refresh the page:

If you go to the site, you'll see that the background scrolls at a different speed as the content and they both end together at the bottom of the page. However, if you refresh the page, the background stops scrolling half way down. I think the background div is srolling much faster than it normally does and is getting to the bottom way too soon. If you click away from the page and then navigate back to it, it works fine. The problem is just on the refresh.

Here is the code for the background div:

```
<div id="background" class="skrollable"
     <?php if (is_page('the-couple')) { ?>
        data-0="background-position:0% 0%;"
        data-end="background-position:0% 100%;">
    <?php } else { ?>
        data-0="background-position:0% 100%;"
        data-end="background-position:0% 100%;">
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I've tried refreshing skrollr on window.load but it didn't seem to fix the problem. Has anyone else run into this? Any solutions?

Comment: Actually it seems that it works fine when the script is loaded from cache, and breaks when it is reloaded. Pretty strange.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Skrollr, but here is what I think happens:

You load your script from cdnjs.cloudflare.com This load is made async. You probably set the scroll speed on your script, and that one is loaded first. **After** that the script from cloudfare is loaded and is probably set at a default speed.

Second time you load the page, both scripts are loaded from cache, and the cloudfare script is probably loaded before.

Solution:

1. Download the script from cloudfare and include it on your page **BEFORE** the speed setting. Just move it first in head as a first test.
2. Set speed and call functions on page load.

Comment: I changed it so I'm hosting the script myself and loading it in the header. But it still is breaking on the refresh...

Comment: Also, I've noticed that this is not a problem on my local version of the site.